# Learning How to Use the Reddit API

Tags: r, api

I am trying to learn how to use the Reddit API

I registered for the API through my Reddit Account (https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps):

[image]

- secret:   ***
- personal_use_script: ****

Using the following link as a reference ( https://alyssafuward.com/2019/02/09/access-reddit-data-using-r-and-the-api/), I tried to connect to the API and run the following query:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

response <- POST("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
                 authenticate('rvhQBG2FCnZ04hIsisDxog', 'J1x4v3QN8DRbIOJbxWczK23-wXC_sg'),
                 user_agent("some_name"),
                 body = list(grant_type="password", 
                             username="abc123456789", 
                             password="987654321cba"))

access_token_json <- rawToChar(response$content)
access_token_content <- fromJSON(access_token_json)
access_token <- access_token_content$access_token
access_token

url <- "https://oauth.reddit.com/LISTING" # try api/v1/me

authorization_bearer <- paste("Bearer ", access_token, sep="")
result <- GET(url, 
              user_agent("some_name"), 
              add_headers(Authorization = authorization_bearer))
result_json <- rawToChar(result$content)
result_content <- fromJSON(result_json)
result_content
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following results:

```
$message
[1] "Bad Request"

$error
[1] 400
```

I think in theory, this is not supposed to produce a "Bad Requests" result?

**Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?**

Thanks!

**Notes:**

- The username/password are not real
- I plan on deleting this API in a few hours
- I create a new Reddit Account for the sake of this question - for the sake of debugging (and if permissible), I can post the username/password info here

Comment: do you successfully get back a string for `access_token` and if you printed the `authorization_bearer` variable is it `Bearer {your string here}`? also here's a good reference. the *400* bad request error could be a number of things so hard to help you troubleshoot, im assuming /LISTING is a valid endpoint, however i feel like `LISTING` is just how they describe returned data structures for the api overall if memory serves correctly?

Comment: @ Carl Boneri: Thank you for your reply! When I run this code - I get the following response:

Comment: > access_token
[1] "2508012135924-dBqTSr-SFrd0Ymi8n0znrdpttOuCIQ"